# How to change nofollow links to dofollow links in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, links, nofollow, dofollow

I am running a self hosted WordPress site and almost all settings run on default. One of my guest author asked me to change the nofollow links to dofollow links. I don't know how to do that for my web site.

Answer (score 2):

[This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dofollow-case-by-case/) should do the job: it allows to add dofollow / nofollow on author basis.